# Keycloak rest-api, deletes user email when updating attributes data

Tags: keycloak, keycloak-rest-api

I'm facing an odd issue with Keycloak REST-API, after updating it from `keycloak:21.0` to `keycloak:22.0`

When using **PUT** against `/admin/realms/<realm>/users/<user_id>`

with the following payload:

```
{'attributes': {'myAttribute': 'XXXXX'}}
```

This has the side effect of cleaning the user's email

But if I use the same endpoint to add a required action
It has no side effect

```
{"requiredActions": ["required_action"]}
```

The REST-API seems to not have a PATCH option for this endpoint

Everything was working fine in `keycloak:21.0`

My current workaround is to also send user email when updating attributes, but it doesn't seems correct

I didn't notice any other user attribute being changed

Any thoughts?

Comment: I tested version 22 and confirmed. it is defect. UI also removed the user email when I update user's attribute.  I tested API too, same symptom but "requiredActions" do not matter "required_action" or " ", Both removed user's email.

Comment: @BenchVue https://github.com/keycloak/keycloak/issues/21751